# Pass Raw Camera ByteArray With Intent

Tags: android, arrays, android-camera, surfaceview, transactiontoolargeexception

I am trying to pass the bytes array from `camera picture callback` using intents for further action. I have created the camera and it works fine using `SurfaceView`.

Here's my method to pass the raw image bytes:

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreviewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("image", bytes);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

This code launches the next activity but a black screen shows up and in logs I can see this exception:

```
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1712172 bytes
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:622)
    at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:915)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1421)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:901)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:7529)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:7600)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:541)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3065)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:570)
```

I have skipped the surfaceview codes, fro brevity.
What options do I have to pass this to next activity? Thanks.

Comment: There is limitations on size for IPC transaction(Bundle). As alternative solution you can save the image to sdcard and send the path further . Or you can hold it in a singleton object.

Comment: Can you post an answer on saving the image to file or a link pls?